# Movie/show/cartoon about a group of poor children who gained powers to turn themselves into "monsters"

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, cartoon

I have memories of this movie/drawing about a group of poor children who gained powers to turn themselves into "monsters".

I remember something involving a children's toy in the beginning of the movie/cartoon (think it was a yoyo but I'm not sure).

Their HQ was an old library where the person or monster who passed the powers to them and send the missions lives.

The villains have equal powers and were also children.

I also remember a betrayal with the good guys in end.

(The only specific scene I remember is a moment where the villains challenge the good guys to a Mesoamerican ballgame on a flying field.)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, if it was animated, was it 2D or 3D animation?

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Guardians of the Lost Code 3D](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1632477/)*** (2010)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Lost_Code):

> *Guardians of the Lost Code* (Spanish: *Brijes 3D*) is a 2010 animated adventure film, created by Ricardo González Duprat, distributed by Videocine.

From IMDB:

> Brijes are magical animal spirits that have been in contact with human beings since the beginning of time. Every human had his brije: The human cared for his brije and vice versa. When the human turned 13 the old shamans performed the ritual a synchronizing ritual trough which the human and the brije were able to transform into the warrior form: a physical state in which the human acquired the powers of his brije and extraordinary strength needed to perform acts of heroism. Unfortunately hundreds of years ago, with the birth of modern science and technology, this union was severed and humans stopped believing in magic.

It's an animated movie about three kids who wander into a storeroom in a history museum and find an ancient stone disc, through which they come into contact with brijes, supernatural creatures they can combine with to assume monstrous "warrior forms."

There's another group of three kids who serve as the antagonists; they were given brijes by an adult antagonist, who lives in a mansion with a large library. And in the third act of the movie, the protagonists take part in a "ceremonial ball game" on a section of ground which is levitated high in the air.

The ball game is discussed at around the 1:00:59 mark in the video below, and begins a few minutes later.